# Symfony : How to translate an email sent by switfmailer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, subscriber

I'm struggling with SF4 to do a simple thing I guess.

After a user registration, I'm trying to send the email according to user locale (french or english).

With $subject, $body texts set in the susbcriber I'm receiving the email.

Now I'd like to implement translations for subject and body.

There are surely things that I don't control very well here but I tried what's described in SF doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#basic-translation) and it's working inside a controller but not inside my subscriber.

I have pretty clear errors that I don't understand :(

[error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GoJv.png)

Any advice to guide me please ?

I know that for the body I could render a twig template but not for the subject of the email.

Here's my subscriber code : (I uncomment what's commented when I'm testing)

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Events;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
//use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class RegistrationNotifySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $mailer;
    private $sender;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $sender)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::USER_REGISTERED => 'onUserRegistrated',
        ];
    }

    public function onUserRegistrated(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getSubject();

        //$subject = $translator->trans('registration.email.subject', array(), 'messages'); -- , TranslatorInterface $translator
        $subject = "Your account for a product demonstration";
        $body = "Hello, Your account has been created...";

        $message = (new \Swift_Message())
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setTo($user->getUsername())
            ->setFrom($this->sender)
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
        ;

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Fab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject Translator into your subscriber. To do this you need

1. Accept it as a parameter in the subscriber constructor
2. Let Symfony know it needs to pass it there by editing `service.yml` file

```php
// # service.yml #
//AppBundle\EventSubscriber\RegistrationNotifySubscriber:
//        arguments: ['@translator', '@mailer']
//        public: true

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class RegistrationNotifySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $mailer;
    private $sender;
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, $sender)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::USER_REGISTERED => 'onUserRegistrated',
        ];
    }

    public function onUserRegistrated(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->getSubject();

        $subject = $this->translator->trans('registration.email.subject', array(), 'messages');
        $subject = "Your account for a product demonstration";
        $body = "Hello, Your account has been created...";

        $message = (new \Swift_Message())
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setTo($user->getUsername())
            ->setFrom($this->sender)
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html')
        ;

        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I knew what had to be done but no clue on how to do it.

Many thanks guys.